# WebApi HttpPost not working with parameters

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web Api project with this route config

```
    var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        "DefaultApiRoute",
        "api/v1/{controller}/{action}");
```

I have two post method

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult RetrieveTestNoParam()
{
    return new JsonResult<string>("This is a test", new JsonSerializerSettings(), Encoding.UTF8, this);
}


[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult RetrieveTest(string input)
{
    return new JsonResult<string>(input, new JsonSerializerSettings(), Encoding.UTF8, this);
}
```

The first one is working but the second one gives this respone

```
{
  "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://test.dev.local/api/v1/NewsApi/RetrieveTest'.",
  "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'NewsApiController' that matches the request."
}
```

This is what I see in fiddler

```
POST http://test.dev.local/api/v1/NewsApi/RetrieveTest HTTP/1.1
Host: test.dev.local
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 261
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
Content-Type: application/javascript
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36
Postman-Token: c2ba631b-4bfd-9379-bf40-0ca1a6a8a3bc
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=4kgfwd2u3pwusfdvdsrkt2vt; SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE=ddd9185a3e8940c9823e81b7d38cdf20|False; sc_expview=0

------WebKitFormBoundaryxdYhzJ7A8WnI8qaa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="input"

Dit is de input
------WebKitFormBoundaryxdYhzJ7A8WnI8qaa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="czczcsdcsdf"

sdfsfsdfsdff
------WebKitFormBoundaryxdYhzJ7A8WnI8qaa--
```

Any ideas?

Other questions I have about Web Api:

Can a controller contain multiple get or post methods?
Do I need the actionname attribute and what does this attribute do?

Regards
Danny

Comment: Please share your client post call

Comment: Are those two action methods located inside same controller? Could you show the URL of `RetrieveTestNoParam`?

Comment: They are in the same controller. I am using postman in Chrome to do a POST. Do you now where can I see the call?

Comment: Try posting to `http://alfa-college.dev.local/api/v1/NewsApi/RetrieveTest?input=test`

Comment: Using ?input works but then it behaves as a get? Don't I need to send formdata in a post? 

I need to send a object to. I can't do that with a ? param

Comment: This is what I eventually wanna pass

public IHttpActionResult Test(int page, IEnumerable<Filter> filters)

Comment: When I add [FromBody] I get a response but my input param is always null public IHttpActionResult Test([FromBody]string input)

Comment: you need to pass the input with the same name as parameter.  i.e  your request object should be  `{ "input" : "test" }`

Comment: if you are using WebAPI2 then you can use `Attribute Based Routing` which is easy to define `routes` as attributes to the `action`

Comment: How would I apply that to code above?